# new Highcharts.Chart creating trouble. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, highcharts

I have the following code:

**assets/javascript/activities.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
    graph = new Highcharts.Chart
        chart: 
            renderTo: "activity_graph"
            type: 'column'

        exporting:
            buttons:
                printButton:
                    enabled: true   
....
```

**assets/javascript/activity_groups.js.coffee**

```
jQuery -> 
    $('ul').children('ul').hide()
```

The activity_group file does not work if I have new Highcharts.Chart in my activities file. If I comment new Highcharts.Chart it works fine. Both files load properly. Why does this happen?

**[Edit1]**

I was playing around I also noticed that If I place `$('ul').children('ul').hide()` before `graph = new Highcharts.Chart` it also works as expected. I don't want to place it in the same file though and I don't want to have to place it in front of the graph variable necessarily.

**[Edit2]**

Found one error why I assume it is not working. I am not very knowledgable with javascript.
Uncaught Highcharts error #13:

Highcharts Error #13

Rendering div not found

This error occurs if the chart.renderTo option is misconfugured so that Highcharts is unable to find the HTML element to render the chart in.

My markup only contains the activity_graph div where I need it( In my activities show view). It is not included anywhere else. That is why I assume I am getting this error. I don't want to use it anywhere else though... Any thoughts?

**[Edit3]**

This is the markup that I am generating with rails:

```
= content_tag :div, "", id: "activity_graph", data: {name: graph.name, minutes: graph.minutes, year: graph.year, month: graph.month, day: graph.day, data_hash: graph.data_hash}
```

I get my div with id activity_graph and the graph is displayed without problems. The error doesn't pop up when I am on this page... However If I navigate on a different page then the error pops up because I don't have this div and the id anymore...

Comment: Please show the markup, may be that can help. Just to add, `highcharts` wont work on `hidden` elements.

Comment: @Jashwant I found one error. I will update my post.

Comment: `renderTo: "activity_graph"` means you need an element with `id=activity_graph` and it should not be `display:none` or `hide()` at the time of calling `highcharts`. Can you show the markup (html) associated with it ?

Comment: @Jashwant does this make sense? [Edit3]

Comment: as you said ' However If I navigate on a different page then the error pops up because I don't have this div and the id anymore...'   If you dont want a graph on other page, dont include the `highcharts` js in that page and if you want chart on other page too, just include an element with id `activity_graph`. Also, always show the html markup not the markup which is to be rendered by rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting a conditional. Only if the div element exists I should renderTo. The error disappeared when I did this.